# Needed precision for detecting effects in experiments

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, home-experiment, data-analysis

I did a bayesian fit to experimental data with a physical model. I notice that some effects cannot be detected due to the precision of the data and the physical model doesn't fit in the best way. So I need to find the required error magnitude of the data that detects these effects.

Does there exist some computational method that will help with my request?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we wish to measure $x$.

Assign every measurement a variable $a, b, c, ...$ such that we can express $x = f(a, b, c, ...)$

Assign every measurement a standard deviation $\sigma_a, \sigma_b, \sigma_c, ...$. Propagate error to obtain $\sigma_x = f(\sigma_a, \sigma_b, \sigma_c, ...)$

Compute $\sigma_a, \sigma_b, \sigma_c, ...$

Compute $\sigma_x$

[how to caclulate standard deviation](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Statistics/Book%3A_Introductory_Statistics_(Shafer_and_Zhang)/06%3A_Sampling_Distributions/6.01%3A_The_Mean_and_Standard_Deviation_of_the_Sample_Mean)

[how to propagate error](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Quantifying_Nature/Significant_Digits/Propagation_of_Error)